# jquery ui dialog page refresh if not open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to wirte a refresh condition if the jquery dialogs are not open. Need fresh set of eyes as it does not seem to work. Code looks like that:

```
if(!$('#add_note-dialog').dialog("isOpen")) { 
    setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 3000);
}
```

The setTimeout function by itself works perectly, when I check the condition with firebug console, it shows proper status, but when I put it in `<script>` ... it simply does not work or when I remove the "!" condition, it refreshes all the time even when the dialog is closed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `#add_note-dialog` a confirm box or something like that?

Comment: Is that supposed to happen on page load? Maybe the dialog is not ready? What does `alert($('#add_note-dialog').dialog("isOpen"))` return? `[Object object]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question basically amounts to:

> - If the dialog is not open:
>
>   - Schedule a page refresh in 3 seconds.

I think you're looking for:

> - Every 3 seconds:
>
>   - If the dialog is not open:
>
>     - Refresh the page.

Or maybe even:

> - Every 3 seconds since page load or since the dialog was last closed:
>
>   - If the dialog is not open:
>
>     - Refresh the page.

The first case can be implemented with [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval):

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    if (!$("#add_note-dialog").dialog("isOpen")) { 
        window.location.reload();
    }
}, 3000);
```

The second case is a little trickier, as it requires binding to the [dialogopen](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open) and [dialogclose](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close) events, and keeping track of the timer id, e.g. with [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/). We also only need a one-shot timer since it will either fire and refresh the page, or be canceled, so [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) will suffice:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_note-dialog")
        // Set initial timer.
        .data("refreshTimer", window.setTimeout(window.location.reload, 3000))
        .dialog({
            /*
             * Your dialog options,
             */
            open: function() {
                // Dialog open, cancel current timer.
                window.clearTimeout($(this).data("refreshTimer"));
            },
            close: function() {
                // Dialog closed, restart timer.
                $(this).data("refreshTimer",
                    window.setTimeout(window.location.reload, 3000));
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: The first case solution is perfect. Thanks Frederic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('#add_note-dialog').is(':hidden')) { 
    setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 3000);
}
```